# Only show two <br>'s out of a group of siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have some pages that are dynamically generated, and in some of them the author has copy and pasted loads of 
 elements.

The markup could be something like:

```
<p>Duties include:
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
 •  Assisting residents with dressing, undressing, bathing and personal care
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
 •  Helping residents with mobility problems and disabilities 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
 •  To care for residents who are unwell i.e. changing dressings and bed nursing
<br>
</p>
```

What I'd like to do is select just two of these br's in a particular group and hide their siblings. I can't hide all of them as they are still used to create a line break in the paragraph.

To be clear, I need to retain 2 of the br's in a particular group, so in between each piece of text in the example above.

I've tried using nth-child with CSS but the amount of br's is unknown and could be many or few.

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Are you saying that they have actually pasted in break tags or that they are generated?

Comment: Training your authors is the best solution, but we all know that's easier said than done.

Comment: We currently have no way of controlling the html, yes they have pasted those breaks in, and we're not doing any stripping server side

Comment: Not possible with CSS....Js is the answer.

Comment: you don't have a ground of control... Your sibling test doesn't make sense because there is no element that can read text and determine what is right after it until the next text because all elements are determined as text... If that makes sense... You need something more solid to base off of.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't even know how JS could do this exactly... it COULD maybe possibly almost likely be able to be done through a crazy regex, but I sadly am unable to think of a simple regex that could do it even remotely close.

Comment: It's easy with CSS only, but only if `Assisting residents with dressing, undressing, bathing and personal care` is wrapped into some tag also.

Comment: @CayceK I agree it it would be convoluted but you'd have to isolate each text node, count the number of break tags in front of it, if there are more than two, delete the extra...Phew! Not something I fancy.

Comment: @dfsq Yeah...but it ain't. :)

Comment: If you're getting "word" like pastes, maybe the solution is to offer them not a plain-text area, but one powered by TinyMCE/similar to actually render the markup into bbcode of sorts for parsing. on the front end.   this would scrub the extra break tags right into a visual scope.    Counting things is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Yes that would be ideal @briansol but at the moment we have no way of controlling the input. This was just to see if there was a quick fix in the mean time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify HTML you have to use javascript. Fortunately it's very easy in this case:

```
$('p').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue);
}).wrap('<span>');
```

and then you use it in combination with a little CSS to tame repeating `br` tags:

```
br + br {
    display: none;
}
```

<sub>* or `br + br + br` depending on how many `br` you want to hide.</sub>

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ff7sb59n/1/

Comment: small problem is `div` isn't a valid child of `p` though

Comment: This looks like the kind of solution I was looking for! Thanks very much

Comment: am I wrong or is this still only retaining 1 br per separation?

Comment: ok you did very well, but I had to say that the other answer is a better answer as it does fully address the question. I sadly would not have come to either solution because you are both using things I have yet to do myself. So good job either way.

Comment: @CayceK Well you can also show two `br` if you want: `bt + br + br` will leave two `br` and hide subsequent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery solution you can build from.

It wraps all the text nodes that aren't whitespace in a span, looks between the spans for extra `br` and removes them, then replaces the temporary span with it's text contents

```
$('p').contents().each(function(){
    if(this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length){
       $(this).wrap('<span class="temp_span">')
    }

});

$('p .temp_span').each(function(){
   var $br = $(this).nextUntil('.temp_span');    
    $br.filter('br:gt(1)').remove()    
}).replaceWith(function(){
    return $(this).text()
});
```

This will allow you to remove the extra breaks **before** storing the data.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w1f87sdn/)**</kbd>

Comment: Much better answer. Actually does what is asked in the question. +1.